# Error -Could not create the Java virtual machine via unix file

Tags: java, jvm, java-native-interface, 32-bit

I have written a unix program with a sample code as follows :

```
export PATH=/usr/java5/jre/bin:$PATH
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java5/jre/bin
export MW_HOME=$UCM_HOME/Middleware

export CLASSPATH=$MW_HOME:$MW_HOME/eaton/


# Verify whether required variables are set
if [ -z "${JAVA_HOME}" ]; then
  printf "\n\nError: Set the following environment variables:\n\n"
  printf "JAVA_HOME            (Absolute path to jdk directory)\n\n"
  exit 1
fi

JAVACMD="${JAVA_HOME}/java"



LIB="${UCM_HOME}/generic/oracle.ucm.fa_genericclient_11.1.1.jar"

config_file="${UCM_HOME}/generic"


echo $config_file
echo "${config_file}/connection.properties"


# jrf-client.jar is a manifest jar with MANIFEST.MF Class-Path referencing required client libraries
CUSTOM_CLASSPATH=$MW_HOME/oracle_common/modules/oracle.jrf_11.1.1/jrf-client.jar

checkerror()
{
  RESULTCODE=$?
  if [ ${RESULTCODE} -ne 0 ];then
    exit 1
  fi
}

${JAVACMD} -Xms512m \
-classpath "${CLASSPATH}:${LIB}" \
-Ducm.prop.default="${config_file}/connection.properties" \
test.oracle.apps.tx.GenericToolUpload "${FILE_LOCATION}/${FILE_NAME}" "${ENTITY_LIST}"

checkerror
exit
```

When i am executing this program. It is going into error with-

```
JVMJ9GC020E -Xms too large for heap
JVMJ9VM015W Initialization error for library j9gc23(2): Failed to initialize
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

user profile was set with 256M. I have increased to 512M

But I am still getting the same error.

I think it is erroring out in `${JAVACMD} -Xms512m \` . But do not know the solution.

Comment: The vast majority of the code is unrelated to the question. Your problem is that your java refuses to start with the param `-Xms512m`. Could you strip that down to start a simple java program with that parameter?

Comment: I dont know java much... hence i am having issue to understand the error

Comment: The message says `-Xms too large for heap` so why can't you just make it smaller? Maybe you wanted `-Xmx` anyway. Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/java.html#BABHDABI to see what the options do